# Can I plant saffron in spring?

Tags: planting, bulbs, storage

I ordered some saffron bulbs and thought they would be delivered in the fall but they are here now. The directions say to plant immediately. These came from China. They were a little moist from being packed in a plastic bag. I have them drying in a bowl right now so they don't get moldy.

Will these be alright to go ahead and plant now or can I store them till fall somehow?

Comment: They bloom in the Fall but vegetative growth happens in Spring and Summer. Someone may tell you how to keep them dormant, but I'd plant them now and allow them to store energy all over the year which is what the directions are telling you as well.

Comment: Can you use regular spring flowering crocus to get saffron ? Anyone try it ?

Answer (score 1):

The advice at [Vegetable Gardener](http://www.vegetablegardener.com/item/2405/how-to-grow-saffron/page/all) is:

> Plant the bulbs (technically they’re corms) in the summer

and at [SaffronBulbs.com](http://www.saffronbulbs.com/culture.htm):

> Planting: from June to mid-September

So neither suggests waiting as long as Autumn.

The corms do not store well, so as @jbcreix, were they mine I would follow the advice that came with them and plant them immediately. That's not exactly summer but probably not enough different to be significant.